# How to programmatically turn on "Network Discovery" in Windows OS?

Tags: c#, windows, upnp

My project open ports using UPnP protocol. Windows disables UPnP device discovery by default, one needs to turn on **Network Discovery** in **Network and Sharing Center** to enable UPnP device discovery.

Is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use cmd command for enable network discovery

```
netsh firewall set service type = upnp mode = mode
```

then give that command as parameter to code

```
public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
{
  try
  {
    // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
    // and "/c " as the parameters.
    // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
    // and then exit.
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
      new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

    // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
    // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // Do not create the black window.
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();
    // Get the output into a string
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the command output.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
  catch (Exception objException)
  {
    // Log the exception
  }
}
```

If that command doesnt work find another command to enable network discovery acording to your system.

Comment: Thanks, I also found "netsh advfirewall firewall" which is useful too: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709

Comment: netsh firewall is depreciated, as Fxam pointed out netsh advfirewall firewall is the replacement so you can pass a command like: "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=\"Network Discovery\" new enable=Yes"