# How to Activate Network Discovery in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, wmi, discovery

I need to know how to enable the "Network Discovery" option in Windows.
I tried to make it with WMI, but i couldn't.
Can someone help me? 
Thank!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Questions are more readily answered on here if you paste the code that you have tried along with the question.

Comment: Do you have any code you could post from what you attempted?

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved here: [How to programmatically turn on "Network Discovery" in Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322177/how-to-programmatically-turn-on-network-discovery-in-windows)

Not sure if you already tried that solution or not, but it should work

Comment: I solved the problem.

Solution:

Change the rule in the windows firewall for "network discovery"

"netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="network discovery" new enable=yes"

This command is executed with System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo and System.Diagnostics.Process in C#.

thanks for reply.

Comment: Please read the Stackoverflow FAQ. You can answer your own questions and accept them so they can be closed. Posting them as a comment on an answer is certainly not the way to go.